# Transform dataframe based on three first rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, transformation

I have a data frame like this (but much bigger) and I am trying to use transform to get the max based ONLY on the first 3 rows of each group.

```
     df10 = pd.DataFrame({
      'Price': [1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50],
      'Stock': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'IBM','IBM','IBM','IBM','IBM']
     })
```

This syntax works for the entire column

```
df10['max_top_3']=df10.groupby("Stock").Price.transform('max')
```

But I want the 'max_top_3' column to show 3 and 30 respectively for AAPL and IBM >> which is the max number of the first 3 entries in that column

I tried something like this and it gave an error

```
df10['max_top_3']=df10.groupby("Stock").Price.head(3).transform('max')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the `head` in transform with a `lambda`:

```
df10.groupby("Stock").Price.transform(lambda x: x.head(3).max())
```

---

```
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     3
4     3
5    30
6    30
7    30
8    30
9    30
Name: Price, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do

```
df10.merge(df10.groupby('Stock').head(3).groupby('Stock',as_index=False).Price.max(),on='Stock')
Out[179]: 
   Price_x Stock  Price_y
0        1  AAPL        3
1        2  AAPL        3
2        3  AAPL        3
3        4  AAPL        3
4        5  AAPL        3
5       10   IBM       30
6       20   IBM       30
7       30   IBM       30
8       40   IBM       30
9       50   IBM       30
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sort](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) the dataframe(unnecessary in your case, since the data is already sorted), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Stock`, then get the 3rd row, using [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html), since data is sorted in descending order :

```
df10["max_3"] = (df10
                 .sort_values(["Price", "Stock"])
                 .groupby("Stock")
                 .Price
                 .transform("nth", 2)
                 )

df10


Price   Stock   max_3
0   1   AAPL    3
1   2   AAPL    3
2   3   AAPL    3
3   4   AAPL    3
4   5   AAPL    3
5   10  IBM     30
6   20  IBM     30
7   30  IBM     30
8   40  IBM     30
9   50  IBM     30
```